# Getting a 404 error on my nodejs webpage (an example webpage being built following a udemy course)

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404

Back again with another development error. This time around i'm getting a 404 error on one of the routes in my nodejs webpage. I've checked for syntax errors everywhere and apparently have none (if you guys spot something I overlooked please do tell me). The routes are registered correctly (at least as far as my understanding of routes in expressjs goes) and the link that should take me to the page (the "a" tag with a class of "btn" in the products.ejs file, line 23) that isn't loading has a correctly spelled route, because of this I am completely bamboozled as to what it could be and need your help!

I'll embed the code I currently have below so you guys can take a look, and if it's not too much to ask please explain to me what went wrong this time.

Thanks to everyone!

p.s.
My terminal isn't throwing any errors from what I could see so I couldn't attach any!

edit-product.ejs file (view):

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/products.css">
</head>
<body>
    <%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs') %>
    <main>
        <form class="product-form" action="/admin/add-product" method="POST">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image Url</label>
                <input type="text" name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="price" id="price" step="0.01">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn" type="submit"><% if (editing) { %>Update product<% } else { %>Add Product<% } %></button>
        </form>
    </main>
<%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
```

product.ejs file (view):

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/products.css">
</head>
<body>
<%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs') %>
    <main>
        <% if (prods.length > 0) {%>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="card">
                <% for (let product of prods) { %>
                <article class="product-item">
                    <header class="card__header">
                        <h1 class="product__title"> <%= product.title %> </h1>
                    </header>
                    <div class="card__image">
                        <img src="<%= product.imageUrl %>", alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__content"> 
                        <h2 class="product__price"> $<%= product.price %> </h2>
                        <p class="product__description"> <%= product.description %> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card__actions">
                        <a href="/admin/edit-product" class="btn"> Edit </a>
                        <form action="/admin/delete-product" method="POST">
                            <button class="btn" type="submit"> Delete </button>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </article>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% } else { %>
            <h1>No Products</h1>
        <% } %>
    </main>
<%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
```

admin.js file (routes):

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const adminController = require('../controllers/admin');

const router = express.Router();

// /admin/add-product => GET
router.get('/add-product', adminController.getAddProduct);

// /admin/product => GET
router.get('/products',adminController.getProducts);

// /admin/add-product => POST
router.post('/add-product', adminController.postAddProduct);

router.get('/edit-product/:productId', adminController.getEditProduct);

module.exports = router;
```

product.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const p = path.join(
    path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), 
    'data', 
    'products.json'
);

const getProductsFromFile = cb =>{
    fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
        if(err) {
            cb([]);
        } else{
            cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        }
    });
};

module.exports = class Product {
    constructor(title, imageUrl, description, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    save() {
        this.id = Math.random().toString();
        getProductsFromFile(products => {
            products.push(this);
            fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }

    static fetchAll(cb) {
       getProductsFromFile(cb);
    };

    static findById(id, cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(products => {
            const product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
            cb(product);
        });
    };
};
```

admin.js file (controller):

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

exports.getAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('admin/edit-product', {
    pageTitle: 'Add Product',
    path: '/admin/add-product',
    editing: false
  });
};

exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const product = new Product(title, imageUrl, description, price);
  product.save();
  res.redirect('/');
};

exports.getEditProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const editMode = req.query.edit;
  if (!editMode) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  const prodId = req.params.productId;
  Product.findById(prodId, product => {
    if(!product) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
    res.render('admin/edit-product', {
      pageTitle: 'Edit Product',
      path: '/admin/edit-product',
      editing: editMode,
      product: product
    });
  });
};

exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
  Product.fetchAll(products => {
    res.render('admin/products', {
      prods: products,
      pageTitle: 'Admin Products',
      path: 'admin/products'
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking yet again at the videos I found the answer to my problem. Everything in the code is written correctly, the problem relies on the url I was using. The problematic route was "/admin/edit-product" because there isn't a route connecting to that view, instead the route in the code is "/edit-product/:productId". My mistake was that I had to specify manually the url in my browser because I haven't coded it otherwise.